# Auto Compression of images Outlook 2013

Tags: image, outlook, compression

I'm currently using both Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2010 in my office. In my signature the image is automatically compressed, is there a a way to turn this off? I have tried JPEG and PNG images but the issue is still there.

I can't find any options to change this behaviour. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your photo editor make sure the image is set to 96dpi, then try inserting the image.